# pgfkeys: set default value to boolean ".is if", and values are changed globally

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I'm quite new with `pgfkeys`, and I'm having troubles to set default values to boolean keys defined with `.is if` (let me know if there is another way to define boolean keys), and I don't know why, but the values are changed globally instead of locally. I tried the following:

```
proof here/.is if=proofhere,
proof here/.initial=true,
```

and two problems:

- by default, `\ifproofhere` is false, despite the `.initial` value
- if I change the value once, it changes the value for all the subsequent calls to my function.

I think I don't use pgfkeys in the good way, but don't know what's wrong.

[image]
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\newif\ifproofhere
\pgfkeys{
  /prAtEnd/.cd, %% Proof at end will be the main path
  proof here/.is if=proofhere,
  proof here/.initial=true,
  no proof here/.style={proof here=false}, % alias
}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\theoremProofEnd{O{}}{
  \pgfkeys{
    /prAtEnd/.cd,
    #1
  }
  \ifproofhere
  The proof is here ! :D
  \else
  Sorry, no proof.
  \fi
}

\begin{document}\noindent\\
Should be ``proof here'': \theoremProofEnd[] === Pb\\
Should be ``proof here'': \theoremProofEnd[proof here]\\
Should be ``no proof'': \theoremProofEnd[no proof here]\\
Should be like first line: \theoremProofEnd[]\\
Should be ``proof here'': \theoremProofEnd[proof here]\\
Should be like first line: \theoremProofEnd[] === Pb
\end{document}
```

-- EDIT --
Thanks for the comments, so using `proof here=true` solve the first problem, but not the "reusability" one: if I change once the value, it's change for the next calls as well. For now I define a `default` style that re-initialize everything, and I call that style at the beginning of my function, but it looks a bit dirty (especially if you nest pgfkeys calls, I guess it can get into troubles). What's the good way to proceed? If I don't, it gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\newif\ifproofhere
\pgfkeys{
  /prAtEnd/.cd, %% Proof at end will be the main path
  proof here/.is if=proofhere,
  proof here=true,
  no proof here/.style={proof here=false}, % alias
  % default/.style = {proof here=true}, %% <= is it the good solution
}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\theoremProofEnd{O{}}{
  \pgfkeys{
    /prAtEnd/.cd,
    % default, %% <= is it the good solution
    #1
  }
  \ifproofhere
  The proof is here ! :D
  \else
  Sorry, no proof.
  \fi
}

\begin{document}\noindent\\
Should be ``proof here'': \theoremProofEnd[]\\
Should be ``no proof'': \theoremProofEnd[no proof here]\\
Should be like first line: \theoremProofEnd[] === Pb\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Imho you can simply use `proof here=true` to set the boolean to true. Or \proofheretrue. But yes, it it looks odd that .initial doesn't work here. You could add an issue at the github site.

Comment: `.initial` doesn't work because `proof here` does not hold a value (it is an if).  The correct way to initialize is `proof here=true` (as is also documented).

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't think that the distinction "value or not" is really clear for a user: The description of the `is if` handler also speaks of "value". In expl3 `.initial:n` works with booleans too (as expected by me).

Comment: @HenriMenke : thanks. It solved one problem, but not the "reusability" one. I updated my question ;)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : Thank you, it solved one problem, but not the "reusability" one. I updated my question ;)

Comment: All you need to do for the second point is to put the environment in a group, e.g. `Should be ``proof here'': \theoremProofEnd[]\\
Should be ``no proof'': {\theoremProofEnd[no proof here]}\\
Should be like first line: \theoremProofEnd[] === Pb\\` (I added `{` and `}`).

Comment: @marmot: ok thanks. I also tried to put it inside the function, and on this example it works, but on my real example it fails because it tries to access references from outside and within the group it fails to solve the references. Groups and defaults style are the only solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately I am a bit lost here. To gauge what is possible and what is not, it is better to have a concrete example that fails. IMHO you might want to ask @HenriMenke to write an answer to the original question and then start a new one in which you provide an explicit example (without all the overhead at the beginning).

Comment: @HenriMenke / Ulrike Fisher: feel free to add an answer so that I can accept ;)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The problem is more generic than `/.is if`. https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/654